# Is there a recommended way to parameterise Gatling simulations?

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I'd like to be able to run Gatling via SBT and parameterize the number of constant users per second and the total duration of the simulation.

Something like:

```
setUp(testScenario.inject(constantUsersPerSec(<parameter>) during(<number> <seconds|minutes|hours>))
```

What would be the best way to pass arguments to SBT and read them in the Simulation class?

Answer (score 1):

You can try pass them as environment parameters

```
  val variable = Option(System.getProperty("variable")) getOrElse """default_value"""
```

and set them in the command :  -Dvariable=yourValue